# NSArray contains two elements but myArray[0] is nil?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsview

I am trying to load a NIB from file.

I have this code, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268778/316469)

```
protocol NibLoadable {
  static var nibName: String? { get }
  static func createFromNib(in bundle: Bundle) -> Self?
}

extension NibLoadable where Self: NSView {

  static var nibName: String? {
    return String(describing: Self.self)
  }

  static func createFromNib(in bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main) -> Self? {
    guard let nibName = nibName else { return nil }
    var topLevelArray: NSArray? = nil
    bundle.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(nibName), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelArray)
    guard let results = topLevelArray else { return nil }
//    let views = Array<Any>(results).filter { $0 is Self }
//    return views.last as? Self
    let element =      results[0] as? Self

    return results[0] as? Self
  }
}
```

results have two elements, a NSView and NSApplication.

The problem here is the `element` is nil. The commented code was also giving me `nil` there.

I am new to swift. What is this `Self` delivering or what it represents on the last line of `createFromNib`?

Comment: what happens if you do let element =      results[1] as? Self. Is it still nil?

Comment: yes. Still nil.

Answer (score 1):

It's not guaranteed that the first object is the requested view.

Get the proper view with `first(where`

And declare `nibName` non-optional as a requirement.

```
protocol NibLoadable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
    static func createFromNib(in bundle: Bundle) -> Self?
}

extension NibLoadable where Self: NSView {    
    static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    static func createFromNib(in bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main) -> Self? {
        var topLevelArray: NSArray? // Optionals are nil by default
        bundle.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(nibName), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelArray)
        return topLevelArray?.first(where: { $0 is Self }) as? Self
    }
}
```

Comment: `createFromNib` still returning nil.

Comment: How do you call `createFromNib`? Is the nib name correct?

Comment: `let myView : MyClass = MyClass.createFromNib()` where `MyClass` is the name of the class this code is into.

Comment: What exactly is this Self supposed to return?

Comment: `Self` is the current type.

Comment: Current type of what, the view? This code loads a XIB in which the file owner is assigned to the class file `MyView`. The view contains a stack with 2 NSTextfields. I guess Self represents the class `MyView`. Is that code equivalent to {$0 isOfKind "MyView"} ?

Comment: Current type of the caller of the method, in your example `MyClass`. To return a textfield the caller must be `NSTextfield`.

Comment: No, I want the view that contains the stack to return. Now that you have mentioned, this is the strange part. The file owner of that nib is of class MyClass. That XIB contains a NSView that contains the stack. This NSView is exactly topArray[0], how to get that element as Self?

Comment: How many views do you have which conform to that protocol? If it's only one the protocol (extension) is pointless. And this particular protocol extension is only useful if the class of the top level object is the requested class.

Comment: in theory, none. This is what I am talking. The XIB contains a file owner and this file owner is the one associated to the class. I have uploaded the files, so you can see, here: https://filebin.net/w5dwgq44fqrj1527/Archive.zip?t=5yzgxbkf THANKS in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After hours trying to fiddle with non-existent documentation, I have come with this, much simpler.

```
  func loadViewFromNib() {

    var topLevelArray : NSArray?

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: .init(String(describing: type(of: self))), bundle: bundle)!
    nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelArray)

    let myView = topLevelArray?.first(where: { $0 is NSView }) as? NSView
    addSubview(myView!)
}
```

Thanks @vadian for all the effort.